# Tensorboard no eval scalars/data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9).

And I run my eval and training in parallel. When I run tensorboard I get the training graphs displayed, but I don't get the mAP or any other graph for eval. The event files are in the eval directory.

I use train.py and eval.py in the tesnorflow/models/research/object_detection/ directory without changing them. Afaik if the eval metrics aren't supplied in the pipeline config it gets set to the pascalvoc metrics by default. Shouldn't I then have at least an mAP graph?